# i want to import a function from another python file which is inside the class

Tags: python-2.7, function, class, import, invoke

I have tried to import like this:
sample_wave is another python file onlistener is the classname and onpartialTranscript is function in it

```
from sample_wave import onPartialTranscript
```

how can i invoke the function inside the class from another file?

```
def create_username():  
   username, pwd  
    try:  
        engine.say("Enter the user name and password for New user")  
        engine.runAndWait()  
        username = add_user(raw_input(onPartialTranscript(username), pwd=getpass.getpass()))  
        engine.say("User Credentials added! %s" % username)  
        engine.runAndWait()  
    except Exception as e:  
        engine.say("recheck credentials")  
        engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot import function from class you should import class and then create object of that class and call that method

```
from sample_wave import onlistener 
x = onlistener();
username = ...
x.onPartialTranscript(username)
```

Comment: still i am facing the import error for the    from sample_wave import onlistener

Comment: from sample_wave import onListener
ImportError: cannot import name onListener in python2.7

Comment: where is you sample_wave file can you post content of file and dir structure

Comment: they are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

You can't import the function directly. However, you could:

1. Import the class and instantiate the object, as stated in earlier answer
2. Rewrite the function
3. Import the class and create your own as its child, overriding `__init__` method

I would vote for 3., it seems to be the cleanest to me.
Besides you can try following experiment. Nevertheless, it can introduce unexpected results, usage of eval is not a good practice for example, etc.

test.py - the module which you want to import from:

```
class onlistener:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def testfunction(self):
        print "Imported"
```

In the following, use inspect module to find the function called testfunction:

```
import inspect
from test import onlistener

def main():
    classfunc = inspect.getsourcelines(onlistener.testfunction)

    # the first field contains the code (list of lines), convert it to string
    my_str = ''
    first = True

    for line in myfunc[0]:
        if first:
            # First line contains 'self' argument, remove it
            line = line.replace('self', '')
            first = False

        # we need to remove the indentation, here it's 4 spaces
        my_str += line[4:]

        # append the call to the function
        # newline is needed due to specification of compile function
        my_str += 'testfunction()\n'

        # create code object
        my_func = compile(my_str, '<string>', 'exec')

        # The last line will call the function and print "Imported"
        eval(my_func)
```